# How to copy a uncertain name file with the command CopyFile in Mathematica

Tags: files-and-directories, copy-as

I have many files named like this "GSM697492_500_D1.CEL", and a another file which contain the first part of the file name like this"GSM697492".
I want to copy the some of the CEL files from one directory to another.How can I do this? I have tried with the following code

```
FileNames["E:\\work\\META分析\\source\\GSE28160_RAW1\\" ~~ cases[[1]] ~~ "*.CEL"]
```

where "case" is a list contain all the file names I want.
the output

```
{"E:\\work\\META分析\\source\\GSE28160_RAW1\\GSM697492_500_D1.CEL"}
```

and then

```
CopyFile["E:\\work\\META分析\\source\\GSE28160_RAW1\\" ~~ cases[[1]] ~~"*.CEL", "E:\\work\\1.CEL"]
```

but the  output is $Failed. Could someone help me with this question? I will appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment, george2079 said "CopyFile on is own does not do filesystem globbing and so the way you have it its looking for a file that literally has a "*" in its name." and you both right.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 CopyFile[First@FileNames[
       "E:\\work\\META分析\\source\\GSE28160_RAW1\\" ~~ cases[[1]]
              ~~"*.CEL"], "E:\\work\\1.CEL"]
```

`CopyFile` on is own does not do filesystem globbing and so the way you have it its looking for a file that literally has a "*" in its name.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, you help me solved this problem